# Angularfire and firebase real-time database

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

I'm working on a project and i wanna try the real time database feature provided by google firebase. Basically it's just a dummy project to demonstrate the working of the real-time database.

I installed the package and the example code for the firestore works. I created data there and i can retrive it. But for the real-time database there are problems.

According to the doc here: https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/database.md#realtime-database

I  should have some observables but they are requireing some kind of query param or so. And i cant get it working.
My component is just a basic empty one. I just wanna get rolling here. I have some data in the real-time database and i wanna retrive and update it.

In my component i have the following import which looks fine:

```
import { Database, object} from '@angular/fire/database';
```

And in the constructor i wanna somehow subscribe to the changes of the database

```
constructor(private db: Database) {
   // this.db.object().subscribe(....  
   //this is not working, object does not exists on 
   //database, although some older example code do something like that. 


// object().subscribe(...   
//i guess something like this should be the good syntax, coz the 
//connection to the firestore is working with something like that. But object needs some //params and i dunno what are those. Also, how this knows the reffenrece to the database? //Importing the Database to the component is totally not neccasary?

  }
```

Can you give me some working code how to subscribe to the database changes, how to get changed element by for example id? How to add new elements programatically from angular?
Is there some docs that are correct and i can read through?

Btw. it's a fresh install i'm using the latest version from everything.

Comment: Did you go through the example code and in particular the [Bind a Collection](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/install-and-setup.md#4-bind-a-firestore-collection-to-a-list) which adds an observer and responds back when items are added to a collection; *Once you've created a items collection and are inserting documents, you should find data streaming into your Angular application and being rendered in your browser*